# Intentionally cause a read/write timeout?

Tags: python, linux, io, monitoring

I'm trying to test some file io and I was wondering if there's a way to emulate the following situation:

I have a block-storage device that is constantly being read/written from, but I want to notify the users of the proper error when they are trying to read/write from a file stored in the block-storage device but the block-storage service/device becomes unavailable or detached mid write. In which case, the read or write command would "timeout," or "hang."

I'm trying to write a test case that reads a file and I want to emulate that situation as closely as possible, meaning I don't want to use `signal` or just some timeout, I want to be able to make some kind of file that will hang a python `file.read()` statement or a `file.write()` statement.

Is this possible? I'm testing on a linux machine and mounting a blockstorage to a folder, pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that [fsdisk](http://www.thirdmartini.com/index.php/Linux_Disk_Failure_Simulation_Driver) is the right tool your looking for. It can bind your storage and inject errors.